# method to increment value of double variable and print in java

Tags: java, oop

I am creating a method that should increase the weight variable value and print  The elephant has eaten 7.5 kilograms of food and now weighs (new weight). 
I am fairly new to java and would be grateful for any help. thank.

```
public class Elephant {

public static void main(String[] args) {
}// end of main
// instance variables

private String name ;
private double weight ;

// constructor
public Elephant(String name, double weight) {
    this.name = "elly";
    this.weight = 100;
}// end constructor
    // getter method

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

// setter method
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setWeight(double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public void Eatting(double kilosOfFood) {
    double consumed = weight + 7.5;
    System.out.println("The eleaphan has eating" +weight +" kilograms of 
    food and now weighs " + consumed + "Kg");
}
}// end of class
```

Comment: i am using eclipse and the code I have here will not print to console

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Always name your methods lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do not understand is what you intend to do with the double kilosOfFood parameter in the Eatting method.

```
It should have been 

public void Eatting(double kilosOfFood) {
            double consumed = weight + kilosOfFood;
            System.out.println("The eleaphan has eating " + this.weight + "kilograms of food and now weighs " + consumed + "Kg");
        }
```

but below will compile correctly

```
public class Elephant {
        private String name ;
    private double weight ;

    // constructor
    public Elephant(String name, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }// end constructor
        // getter method

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    // setter method
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void Eatting(double kilosOfFood) {
        double consumed = weight + 7.5;
        System.out.println("The eleaphan has eating " + this.weight + "kilograms of food and now weighs " + consumed + "Kg");
    }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
           Elephant e = new Elephant("EE", 10.00);
           e.Eatting(2.5);
        }
    }


    The eleaphan has eating 10.0kilograms of food and now weighs 17.5Kg
```

You need to make changes to your main method, plus correct the grammar.

Comment: that worked perfect, appreciate the help

Comment: great, you can mark the answer as correct ,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `main` method to invoke the call to `Eatting` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Elephant elephant = new Elephant("name",10.0D);//with which you want to insantiate the elephant object
   elephant.Eatting(7.5);
 }
```

Also, change your `Eatting` method to use the argument passed.

```
public void Eatting(double kilosOfFood) {
    double consumed = weight + kilosOfFood;
    System.out.println("The eleaphan has eating" +kilosOfFood+" kilograms of food and now weighs " + consumed + "Kg");
}
```

Comment: `...` in original answer were placeholder that more code goes in here and it does not require any change.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the class Elephant. Also in the constructor you do NOT want to set the name or weight of anything. For example everytime you create an instance of the Elephant class in your code, your elephants name will always become "Elly" and weight will always equal "100". This is bad coding because it negates the purpose of the setter.

Comment: Agree on the point, that parameters passed in constructor are not used and member variables are defaulted to some values. I was not changing the constructor and any other code for OP, just wanted to show how to call the methods on an Elephant instance from main method.

Comment: Oh I know! Just wanted to clear up that for him! Since being a new guy